# Show that $f$ is identically zero

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

*Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ there exists an $x \in (a,b)$ such that $|f(x)| < b - a$. Show that $f=0$ on $\mathbb{R}$*

I tried to show it by the epsilon-delta definition of continuity. I assumed that there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c) \neq 0$. But I couldn't obtain any contradiction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you wrote $x\in\Bbb R$, did you mean $x\in(a,b)$?

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: If you write $b$ as $a+\epsilon$, for arbitrarily small positive $\epsilon$, does that give you any ideas?

Comment: @JonathanZ, yes I think it will proceed as the second answer. Thank you so much for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $f$ is nonzero: there is some $x_0$ with $f(x_0)\neq 0$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $$x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{|f(x_0)|}{2}.$$
Note that you can additionally choose $\delta$ so small that $2\delta\leq \frac{|f(x_0)|}{2}.$

Thus $$x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\implies |f(x)|>\frac{|f(x_0)|}{2}.$$

Applying the hypothesis with $a=x_0-\delta$ and $b=x_0+\delta$ yields the existence of $c\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$  such that $|f(c)|<2\delta \leq \frac{|f(x_0)|}{2}$.

This is a contradiction.

Comment: Even simpler: $f(x)=x$.

Comment: I edited the question now.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{R}$. By assumption, for every $h>0$ there exists a point $x_h\in (a,a+h)$ such that $|f(x_h)|<h$. Since $x_h\to a$ when $h\to 0^+$, passing to the limit in the previous inequality, you get (because of the continuity of the modulus function and of $f$) that
$$|f(a)|\leq 0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume to the contrary that there is some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(a) \neq 0$, WLOG, we can assume $f(a) > 0$ (because otherwise, we can simply consider $g = −f$ here instead of $f$). By continuity at $a$, there is $\delta > 0$ s.t. $f(x) > \dfrac{1}{2}f(a)$ for $|x − a| < \delta$. Let $x_1,x_2 \in B_{\delta}(a)$ be s.t. $x_1 < x_2$ and $x_2 − x_1 < \dfrac{1}{2}f(a)$. By assumption,we can find $x_3 \in (x_1,x_2)$ with the property $f(x_3) < x_2 − x_1 < \dfrac{1}{2}f(a)$ while on the other hand $f(x_3) > \dfrac{1}{2}f(a)$ since $x_3 \in B_{\delta}(a)$. Hence, we have both $f(x_3) < \dfrac{1}{2}f(a)$ and $f(x_3) > \dfrac{1}{2}f(a)$ cannot be true. so there is a contradiction and $f$ must be identically zero.